# How to automatically create bugs in TFS 2015 based on SonarQube reported issues?

Tags: sonarqube, tfs-2015

I have integrated SonarQube 5.6.6 (with default configuration) with TFS 2015 Builds (not XAML build definitions) and I am successful in analyzing projects. Please find below Build definition and generated report at SonarQube local portal.

[image]

[image]

Now what I am trying to accomplish is to port all the bugs, vulnerabilities and Code Smells reported by SonarQube as bugs (typical TFS Work Items) in TFS 2015. I am not able to find any related configuration or options to create TFS bugs. So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do? Does SonarQube supports this feature out of the box?
2. If so, then please share online resources/tutorials to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve what you want. And there are 2 goods reasons for this:

- The first one is that an issue is too granular to be represented by a TFS work item. Picture this: an analysis can create dozen or hundreds of issues: how can you manage all your backlog that will be "polluted" by all the work items created for every single issue?
- The second reason is that instead of trying to manage issues that need to be fixed in a kind of action plan (= list of work items), it's more interesting to fix them along the way while you are developing. This is what we explain in the blog post called ["Stop planning; fix the leak"](https://blog.sonarsource.com/stop-planning-fix-the-leak/).